# Compare the Days of Two Dates

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I'm using ASP.NET, C# and SQL Server. In the database the date is: `2014-10-28`. Just year, month and day, no time portion.

I have this code:

```
  DateTime data1 = new DateTime();
  DateTime data2 = DateTime.Now;

  data1 = reader.GetDateTime(3);

  double total= (data2 - data1).TotalDays;
  Response.Write(total.ToString());
```

The only problem of this is the output. The output of this is "4,81351624131366". Because probably this is the difference of the hours. Its possible to set the data2 to give me just the Y,M and D?

Or convert the total into days?

Comment: You could use `DateTime.Today` instead of `DateTime.Now`... note that that uses the system default time zone to obtain the current date - is that what you want?

Comment: wow thats one easy. Thanks very mutch 100% work

Comment: found something that you can check out [C# compare the days of 2 dates](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=C%23%20compare%20the%20days%20of%202%20dates)

Comment: Side note: don't add extra tags that are not directly related to your question. The fact that you read data from SQL and not console or other place have no impact on DateTime calculations. Also check out [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts) post on adding "thank you notes" to question.

Answer (score 0):

The property `TotalDays` returns the fractional portion of days too. Since the date you're comparing was 4 days ago at midnight, you're getting 4 full days and an additional 4/5th of a day (since it's not exactly midnight when you're executing this).

Either what Jon said (use `DateTime.Today` instead of `DateTime.Now` to get the date portion with a time of midnight), or use the `Days` property, which will just return a rounded 4 and drops the fractional portion.